# Enumerating hexahedral cell vertices and faces in arbitrary dimension

Tags: high-dimensional, mesh-traversal, combinatorics

I have a Cartesian mesh in $d$ dimensions, and I would like to enumerate all the subcells of a given hexahedral cell. If I am just enumerating the vertices of a cell (or cells that contain a vertex) I can use [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), here is my [code](http://petsc.cs.iit.edu/petsc/petsc-dev/annotate/f99e0009e573/include/sieve/CartesianSieve.hh#l219) doing that.

You can see that this works because the Gray code sequence traverses the vertices of a [hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube), which is exactly what a $d$-dimensional hexahedralcell is. If the mesh is a tensor product (Cartesian), then the dual mesh is also made up of hypercubes and we can traverse cells around a vertex using the same algorithm.

How can this strategy be extended to handle edges and faces? Or, what strategy could handle them in a dimension independent way?

Comment: I wasn't sure what an "ireversal" is. If my retags are wrong, please feel free to undo.

Comment: Thanks, it was meant to be 'traversal', but I have to type with one hand holding the baby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suggest, the binary representation works because the **binary numbers with $d$ digits** can be thought of as vectors representing the **coordinates of the vertices of the $d$-dimensional hypercube**.  Now notice that the coordinates of an edge midpoint can be obtained by averaging the coordinates of two (adjacent) vertices and the coordinates of a face midpoint can be obtained by averaging the coordinates of two edge midpoints.

This suggests using a ternary (base 3) system, with each digit equal to 0, 1, or 2.  Consider a hypercube whose volume is the tensor product of the intervals $[0,2]$.  Then the coordinates of the vertices are all the $d$-digit ternary numbers with each digit equal to 0 or 2.  The edge midpoint coordinates are all the $d$-digit ternary numbers with *one digit equal to 1* and the remaining digits equal to 0 or 2.  The face midpoint coordinates are all the $d$-digit ternary numbers with *two digits equal to to 1* and the remaining digits equal to 0 or 2.  This extends in the obvious way to higher-dimensional analogues of faces.

So for instance, the **vertices** of a cube ($d=3$) are

```
(0,0,0)
(0,0,2)
(0,2,0)
(2,0,0)
(0,2,2)
(2,0,2)
(2,2,0)
(2,2,2)
```

The **edges** are

```
(0,0,1)
(2,0,1)
(0,2,1)
(2,2,1)
(0,1,0)
(2,1,0)
(0,1,2)
(2,1,2)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,2)
(1,2,2)
(1,2,0)
```

and the **faces** are

```
(1,1,0)
(1,1,2)
(1,0,1)
(1,2,1)
(0,1,1)
(2,1,1)
```

Thinking about these coordinates even gives a simple way even to determine the number of $n$-faces of a $d$-dimensional hypercube.  These correspond to all $d$-digit ternary numbers with $n$ digits equal to 1 and the remaining digits equal to 0 or 2, so there are $2^{d-n}\cdot {d\choose{n}}$ of them.

Two things I haven't addressed are:

1. Ordering; the Gray code's ingenuity is that adjacent vertices in the list are adjacent in space.  I think you could achieve this with the representation I've described using an approach similar to Gray's, but the question doesn't specifically mention ordering so I didn't worry about it.
2. How to code this up.  This is more of a programming question, and shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks! I will get to work on the ordering question. This should allow arbitrary dimensional Cartesian grid FEM with $\mathcal{O}(1)$ space for the grid.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to labeling all edges and faces there are also other questions I have found important in the same context:

- Numbering them in some particular way. deal.II uses a numbering where we first consider
  all edges that are parallel to the x-axis and sort them by their y,z-values (either 0 or 1) in lexicographic order, then all edges parallel to the y-axis and numbering them by their x,z-values, etc.
- As for the total number: In 1d, there are ne_1=1 edge. In 2d, the square is formed by replicating the 1d line twice at y=0 and y=1, making for two lines, but then we also have to connect all nv_1=2 vertices of old and replicated line, so ne_2=2*ne_1+nv_1=2+2=4. Then construct the cube by replicating the two squares and connecting all vertices, so ne_3=2*ne_2+nv_2=2*4+4=12. You get the recursion.